# DismissViewControllerAnimated dismiss more than 1 controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

This is my project configuration :

`UINavigationController1` -> `UIViewController1` -> `UINavigationController2` -> `UIViewController2` -> `UIViewController3` -> `UIViewController4`

In the `UIViewController4` I do : 
`self.presentViewController(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

When I finished my job in this controller, I do : 
`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

This last action don't close just newController and show me `UIViewController4`, but show me `UIViewController1`

`deinit{print("test")}` of random others controllers in the `UINavigationController1` are called.

I want dismiss only the `newController` and show the `UIViewController4`.

I can't push/pop the controller because this is a libraryController that is call.

How i can do ?

Comment: why you using UINavigationController2 , try by only using UINavigationController1, Thanks

Comment: I use a second NavigationController because I use a tabar. If I remove the NavigationController2 I think the dismiss bring me to the first app controller

Answer (score 0):

User below code to deismiss perticular view

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           {
                            if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController()
                            {
                                topController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                            }
            })
```

For check super view controller use below code

```
if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {
                        print("From Super View \(topController)")
                    }
```

And create one extension

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(viewController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = viewController as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = viewController?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presented)
        }

        if let slide = viewController as? SlideMenuController {
            return topViewController(slide.currentViewController)
        }
        return viewController
    }
}
```